# showing hidden dockwidget in qt

Tags: qt, widget, hide, show, dock

hi i create a dockwidget which i am starting it as hidden. The problem is that afterwards i cannot show it, while i can get the status correctly from the isHidden() function. The weird thing is that if i start the dockwidget not hidden, it works perfect. I am including an example that reproduces this strange behaviour.

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:

    void showDock();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QDockWidget *dock;
    QPushButton *button;


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

//    QMainWindow mainWindow;
//    QDockWidget *dock = new QDockWidget(&mainWindow);
    QDialog *dockDialog = new QDialog(this); // <---------edit: you need to create a parent widget for the dock
    dock = new QDockWidget(dockDialog);

    dock->setStyleSheet("QDockWidget { font: bold }");
    dock->setFloating(true);
    dock->setFeatures(QDockWidget::DockWidgetVerticalTitleBar | QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable);
    QAbstractButton *floatButton = dock->findChild<QAbstractButton*>("qt_dockwidget_floatbutton");
    if(floatButton)
        floatButton->hide();

    dock->setAllowedAreas( Qt::NoDockWidgetArea );
    dock->setWindowTitle("Tools");

    this->addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea, dock, Qt::Vertical);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow(dock); // <------edit: set the dock to be the parent for the window
    window->setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);
    QToolBar *bar = new QToolBar(window);

    bar->setMovable(false);
    bar->addAction("Select");
    bar->addAction("Polygon");
    bar->addAction("Brush");
    bar->addAction("Erazer");
    bar->addSeparator();
    bar->addAction("Mark");
    bar->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    bar->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);

    window->addToolBar(Qt::LeftToolBarArea, bar);
    window->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

    window->setParent(dock);
    dock->setWidget(window);
    dock->hide();            // <------------ comment this line and it will work, edit: you do not need to do that anymore, it is working nicely now

    button = new QPushButton("show", this);
    button->setCheckable(true);

    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showDock()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::showDock()
{
//    qDebug() << "hello";
    if(button->isChecked()){
        if(dock->isHidden()){
            qDebug() << "hidden";
        dock->setFloating(true); // <-----edit: you need to add these lines in order to be able to see the dialog that contains the dock widget, i do not know why i need to that again since in the initialization i already specifying that my dock is floatable
        QAbstractButton *floatButton = dock->findChild<QAbstractButton*>("qt_dockwidget_floatbutton"); // <---------edit: add this lines in order to get rid off the floating button
        if(floatButton)
            floatButton->hide(); // <----edit: the same as previous
        dock->show();
        }
    }

    if(!button->isChecked()){
        if(!dock->isHidden()){
            qDebug() << "not hidden";
            dock->hide();
        }
    }
}
```

as it is now the above code the dockwidget is not appearing in the screen. If you try to comment the line that i am specifying in the mainwindow.cpp it works, but the point is that i want to start the dockwidget hidden. Does someone have any idea, of what is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: @Nemanja's proposal did not work, exactly as i wanted but he gave some hints, in order to make it work as i would like. I have already added the modifications. I do not know if it is the proper way, as i am doing it, but it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parent of the `QDock` control should be your `window` widget, and not object of the `MainWindow` class.

So, you need to replace this:

```
 dock = new QDockWidget(this);
```

with this:

```
QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow(0); // I smell a potential leak here (set the parent!)
dock = new QDockWidget(window);
```

Control is visible when you press Show button in the first case, too, but it is somewhere outside the window, so you may not see it. Also, there is no need to create separate instance of `QMainWindow` inside class that is already inheriting `QMainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you show()/hide() your dockwidget. I haven't tried it myself but maybe you should hide and show the dockwdiget with the [QDockWidget::toggleViewAction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#toggleViewAction) method.